# MVC 4 DataAccess assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have a problem that i do not understand with a MVC4 with EF 5 Code First database. Here is the code :

```
Ligne 193 :            if (db.Persons.Any())
Ligne 194 :            {
Ligne 195 :                var author = (from a in db.Persons
Ligne 196 :                              where a.Uid == uid
Ligne 197 :                              select a).SingleOrDefault();
```

The error message is on line 195 : "Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'DataAccess' ou une de ses dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable." in french which means something like "Impossible to load the file or assembly 'DataAccess' or one of its dépendances. The file can't be find".

As you can see, i can connect to the db on line 193 and have check that the line exist in the database. This error occures on some pages but not on all. As example, i can list the persons and "objects" related in an index, i can create both persons and objects related like companies

```
public class Person
{
    //... things
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies {get;set;}
}
```

So, have you an idea of why i have this DataAccess error and why not everywhere please ?

Thank you

Comment: did you placed you'r data access layer in assembly called "DataAccess"  ?

Comment: Run the Fusion log viewer. It will tell you where .NET looks for DataAccess and what it rejected in the process.

Comment: In french, here is the complete error message : Impossible de définir l'initialiseur de la base de données du type 'System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[Skalae.Web.Model.PortfolioModelContext, DataAccess], [DataAccess.Migrations.Configuration, DataAccess]], EntityFramework, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' pour le type DbContext 'Skalae.Web.Model.PortfolioModelContext, DataAccess' spécifié dans la configuration de l'application.

Comment: I understand that is the EF5 System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion which cause the problem but not where it is. When i rebuild the project and start it in debug (F5), the error does not appear.